# String Comparisons with chars

Tags: c#, string, char

I want to compare a string to another string in c#, in this example

```
 string Text1 = "123bob456";
 string Text2 =  "bobishere";
```

I want to say, if more that 3 (or more) chars match in sequence then return true, in this case it would be true as they both contain "bob".
but I do not know how to do this, could you please help and sorry if this is a repeated question I dint know how to word it.

Comment: Is it any three characters that must match, or is it a sequence of three characters?

Comment: forgot to add, i mean sequence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is the [longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring), which can be solved in time proportional to the sum of the length of the two strings. See the link for possible algorithms.

If you're willing to take a bit of a performance hit, you can do it more simply by considering every sequence of 3 characters in the first string and searching for that sequence in the second. Here is an example (I'm not very familiar with C#, so please forgive any syntax errors):

```
for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length - 2; i++)
    if (s2.Contains(s1.Substring(i, 3)))
        return true;
return false;
```

Your choice will depend on your particular problem. I would try the second approach and revise if it is too slow.

Comment: so what would you recommend?, and as for the later one, i am planing to do this with 400 strings so i would prefer it to be quick

Comment: Changed from `s1.Length - 3` to `s1.Length - 2` to catch the case where the matching substring is at the end of `s1`.

Comment: You can use `s2.Contains(s1.Substring(i,3))` for easier readability.

Comment: When you say 400 strings, how will you compare them? Find every match between pairs from the 400 strings? Use it for grouping or clustering?

Comment: for grouping icon names to folder names

Answer (score 1):

This extension works:

```
public static bool ContainsSubstring(this string string1, string string2, int minLength, StringComparison comparison)
{
    if (minLength <= 0) throw new ArgumentException("Minimum-length of substring must be greater than 0", "minLength");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(string1) || string1.Length < minLength) return false;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(string2) || string2.Length < minLength) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < string1.Length - minLength + 1; i++)
    {
        string part1 = string1.Substring(i, minLength);
        if (string2.IndexOf(part1, comparison) > -1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

for example:

```
string Text1 = "123bob456";
string Text2 =  "bobishere";
bool contains = Text1.ContainsSubstring(Text2, 3, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);  // true
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/lXRrVB)

Comment: This works also and i will save this to one of my class's thanks